# React How do I make the page allows scrolled down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create a chat message and I have no idea how to make the chat be scrolled down every time. When the user inputs new messages, I want it to be always scrolled down so that we can see the new message at the bottom. I feel like this is what needs to be edited.

```
const MessageContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
`
```

Comment: Is the usecase is: when user press send button the window add to scroll to the bottom or when a new message is added in the chat room?

Comment: When the new message is added in the chat room, I want it to stay on the bottom so that you dont have to keep scrolling down to see the new messages

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a dummy div at the bottom of your chat and then scroll to it whenever your component is updated (i.e. state updated as new messages are added):

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
const [text, setText] = useState(1);
const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
};
useEffect(scrollToBottom, [message]);

const addText = () => {
  setMessage([...message, text]);
  setText((data) => data + 1);
}

return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="data">
      {message.map(m => (
        <span key={m}>{m}</span>
      ))}
      <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
    </div>
    <button onClick={addText} className={'button'}>Add Text</button>
  </div>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-feynman-5m3i7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Wow this one worked like a charm as well! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @YongPark please upvote if this answer worked for you, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
const MessageContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    overflow-y: auto;
`
```

Or

I make sample(CodeSandBox) for you, but I'm not sure if this is what you want.

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

It likes :

[image]

Hope to help you !

Comment: wow thank you so much!
My code looks like this https://gist.github.com/pyongho1/cc247e6b1a56815f7525e91094b2544f

will it be possible for you to look at it for me as well?