# How to scroll messages to bottom on click on Send button in Chat App?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In a React project, I've created Chat Section. All designing and functionalities done, except that when messages are sent it doesn't automatically scroll down. What could be the best possible solution?

Here is the code for reference

```
const MessageApp = () => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");
  const [textMessages, setTextMessages] = useState([]);
  const [newTextValue, setNewTextValue] = useState("");
  const [showSenderMessage, setShowSenderMessage] = useState(false);
  const [showRecieverMessage, setShowRecieverMessage] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newData = localStorage.getItem("messages");
    setTextMessages(newData);
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setShowSenderMessage(true);

    if (textValue != "") {
      setTextMessages([...textMessages, textValue]);

      localStorage.setItem("messages", textMessages);
      setTextValue("");
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {showSenderMessage &&
        textMessages.map((text) => (
          <div
            className="bubble-sender"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              justifyContent: "flex-start",
              width: "80%"
            }}
          >
            <span style={{ width: "20%" }}>
              <img
                alt="blank profile"
                src="https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png"
                style={{
                  height: "50px",
                  width: "50px",
                  border: "2px solid black",
                  borderRadius: "50%"
                }}
              />
            </span>

            <span style={{ width: "80%" }}>
              {text}
              <br />
              <span
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexWrap: "wrap",
                  justifyContent: "flex-end"
                }}
              >
                <small style={{ color: "grey", float: "right" }}>
                  11:23 AM
                </small>
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}

      <span>
        <form
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            bottom: "0",
            marginBottom: "80px",
            width: "100%"
          }}
        >
          <div className="col-lg-10 mb-3">
            <div className="input-group mycustom">
              <input
                value={textValue}
                type="text"
                required
                placeholder="Send Message"
                maxLength="30"
                onChange={(e) => setTextValue(e.target.value)}
              />
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    display: "flex",
                    flexWrap: "wrap",
                    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
                  }}
                  onClick={sendMessage}
                >
                  Send Message
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </span>
    </>
  );
};

export default MessageApp;
```

Following is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-montalcini-bpdsp

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66383844/14522591) can helps you

Comment: Ok but, I'am getting 'scrollIntoView' as null

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./MessageApp.css";

const MessageApp = () => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");
  const [textMessages, setTextMessages] = useState([]);
  const [newTextValue, setNewTextValue] = useState("");
  const [showSenderMessage, setShowSenderMessage] = useState(false);
  const [showRecieverMessage, setShowRecieverMessage] = useState(false);
  const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
  useEffect(scrollToBottom, [textMessages]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const newData = localStorage.getItem("messages");
     setTextMessages(newData.split(","));
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setShowSenderMessage(true);

    if (textValue != "") {
      // const newTextValueHere = textValue;
      // setNewTextValue(newTextValueHere);
      // setTextValue("");
      setTextMessages(preVal=>[...preVal,textValue]);

      localStorage.setItem("messages", textMessages);
      setTextValue("");
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {showSenderMessage &&
        textMessages.map((text) => (
          <div
            className="bubble-sender"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              justifyContent: "flex-start",
              width: "80%"
            }}
          >
            <span style={{ width: "20%" }}>
              <img
                alt="blank profile"
                src="https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png"
                style={{
                  height: "50px",
                  width: "50px",
                  border: "2px solid black",
                  borderRadius: "50%"
                }}
              />
            </span>

            <span style={{ width: "80%" }}>
              {text}
              <br />
              <span
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexWrap: "wrap",
                  justifyContent: "flex-end"
                }}
              >
                <small style={{ color: "grey", float: "right" }}>
                  11:23 AM
                </small>
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}

      <span>
        <form
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            bottom: "0",
            marginBottom: "80px",
            width: "100%"
          }}
        >
          <div className="col-lg-10 mb-3">
            <div className="input-group mycustom">
              <input
                value={textValue}
                type="text"
                required
                placeholder="Send Message"
                maxLength="30"
                onChange={(e) => setTextValue(e.target.value)}
              />
              <div className="input-group-prepend">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    display: "flex",
                    flexWrap: "wrap",
                    justifyContent: "space-evenly"
                  }}
                  onClick={sendMessage}
                >
                  Send Message
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </span>


      <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MessageApp;
```

here a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-microservice-mlr10?file=/src/components/MessageApp.js:961-1005) based on yours ( I just remove commented code).
I have fixed a bug on your setTextMessages where the app return an iterator error.
You will need to make some style adjustment because for now the new message is "hide" under the input field.

### UPDATE

your const newData is typeOf string so you need to split it in your `setTexMessage()` like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const newData = localStorage.getItem("messages");

    setTextMessages(newData.split(","));
   }, []);
```